# Displaying columns that contain no data

Tags: crystal-reports

These is a sample data that I'm getting right now:

[image]

... where row 3 of the header is a 'Priority'. Group 3 has no records with Priority 1, 3, or 4, so the report only shows 1 column with Priority 2 for that group. What I need is to display all 4 columns for each group, even if there are no records with this priority, it just should have zeros as a count in that column. Here is an example of what this should look like:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your database is set up, try this:

Go to file -> report options -> and check "Convert Database NULL Values to Default" and "Convert Other NULL Values to Default." The reason why it's doing this, is because the value is not 0, it is actually just null.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an 'expected' table with the PK values from your source table. Including even the ones without data, then left outer join the expected table with your actual source.

Or you can use a 'union all' on the rows from your source table *and* the stub rows with values of zero instead of null.